# Ansible service module not starting supervisor with state restarted

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible handler to restart supervisor

```
---
- name: 'restart supervisor'
  become: true
  service:
    name: supervisor
    enabled: yes
    state: restarted
```

And the handler runs but the output is `skipping`

```
RUNNING HANDLER [supervisor : restart supervisor] *******************
skipping: [redacted]
```

The notification happens on the initial provision of the server so supervisor is NOT running when the handler fires. Is this why it isn't restarting? If I ssh into the box and manually run `sudo service supervisor restart` when the service isn't running, it starts up just fine.

I even tried a `start supervisor` handler like this and it did the same thing...skipping and supervisor never started?

```
---
- name: 'start supervisor'
  become: true
  service:
    name: supervisor
    enabled: yes
    state: started
```

I'm running v2.3.0.0-1 but was also experiencing this issue using v2.2.2.0.

Has anyone else run into this issue with supervisor? Is there an alternative approach? Am I doing something wrong?

**-- UPDATE --**

There was a `when` clause where the role was being applied, so I decided to remove that to see if it was the culprit. Skipped again...here's the output.

```
RUNNING HANDLER [supervisor : restart supervisor] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [ansible1] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False", 
    "skipped": true
}
```

It would be nice if ansible would show me what the condition was that caused it to skip because after removing the `when` there is NO reason in my ansible code that would cause it to skip. There must be something internal to the `service` module that is causing this :s

Comment: Please post the full (but minimal) code. If you get "skipped" status it has nothing to do with what's inside the task (provided it looks like in the question), but rather what's outside of it.

Comment: Do you apply your role with `when` statement?

Comment: I'm having the very same issue trying to restart datadog agent. Did you get any update on this?

Comment: Any resolution on this at all? Having this issue with trying to restart a service myself!

Answer (score 1):

Is the handler part of a dependent role? (i.e: the role that defines the handler is included in your role as a dependency in meta/main.yml). Because I've seen this happening and with the same weird `"skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",`. Changing the way the dependent role was included from the `meta/main.yml:dependencies` into the `playbook.yml:roles` made it work.

I've also seen it working if the role that owns the handler is included as meta dependency of a role included as `playbook.yml:roles`.

Not sure if this is a bug or a tricky behaviour that I don't get to understand. This happened on Ansible-playbook 2.3.2.0

Comment: Thanks @Carlos as a matter of fact the supervisor role is included in the meta/main.yml from another role. This makes sense in my case because we're using the supervisor role in another playbook but it's included in the `roles` list of that playbook and runs fine. I will look into this as soon as I have  chance. Thanks for info!

Answer (score 0):

The service module does not call the service script with the restart option, but does a start and stop.  Does the supervisor service script have a status option?  If it cannot get the status, it may not run the restart command at all.

Comment: Looking at the module code, this answer seems to be pretty imprecise.

Comment: Yup -- finally got time to run a test.  Lack of a status option will not cause that problem.